# Python script using SPI as a service on boot

Tags: raspbian-jessie, spi

I wanted to display IP address using MAX7219 and SPI on the startup.

I followed instructions on web page
[Getting a Python script to run in the background (as a service) on boot](http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/).  Script is loaded as required, but the process does not start.  On the other hand, by starting script manually, everything is OK.

I suspect that problem might be in the fact that script starts *before* spidev is loaded.  Or is there anything else wrong?  Can you help me with this?

Here is also code in case you need it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import max7219.led as led
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def run_cmd(cmd):
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    return(p.communicate()[0].rstrip())

addr = '  ' + run_cmd("ip addr show wlan0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1")

dots = [False]*(len(addr)-3)

pos=-1
for i in range(0,3):
    pos = addr.find('.', pos+1)
    dots[pos-i-1] = True
addr = addr.replace('.','')

device = led.sevensegment()

pos = 0
while True:
    addrs=addr[-pos:]+addr[:-pos]
    dotss=dots[-pos:]+dots[:-pos]
    for i in range(0,8):
        device.letter(deviceId=0,position=8-i,char=addr[i],dot=dots[i])
    time.sleep(1)
    pos=pos-1
    if pos == -len(addr): pos=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a shellscript code in rc.local to check `lsmod | grep -c <your_module_name>` greater than zero, and start your python code after it's loaded. or - just load it via modprobe in rc.local.

Comment: If I understand you right, your answer is not about correcting the described problem but about proposing of a new solution?

Comment: @Pygmalion yes, the solution is new, but it solves not just this problem, but a packo of similar ones. I fount it myself with a very *odd* behaviour of some RTL chipset based WiFi USB dongles : it boots, no auto-load of driver, lsusb states the device, iwconfig and ifconfig seems not to be recognizing it. Auto-loading in boot config *does not solves the issue*! WTF?! But this rc.local tweak works just like a charm...